# Compile Delphi 7 code in Delphi xe2

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, delphi-7

I am working with another developer team and they have a code writen in Delphi 7 that doesn't work because of the functionality of TStringStream. So they ask me for help with this but I'm using Delphi xe2.

Is there any way to change the compiler options in my Delphi xe2 IDE and see the behavior of the code in Delphi 7?

Comment: @RemyLebeau posted a [`TAnsiStringStream`](http://embarcadero.newsgroups.archived.at/public.delphi.rtl/201105/1105165007.html) to be used with legacy projects.

Comment: Actually, the other team said to me that there is not function LoadFromFile for TStringStream in Delphi 7. That is the mayor problem.

Comment: In D2009+, `TStringStream` is derived from `TBytesStream`, which is derived from `TMemoryStream`. There `LoadFromFile` is implemented. You can easily backport `TMemoryStream.LoadFromFile` and `TMemoryStream.LoadFromStream` into `TAnsiStringStream`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no compiler settings that can be used to revert the compiler/RTL to pre-Unicode state.

If you want to compile in a Unicode Delphi, you have to make code changes. The other obvious option is to use a pre-Unicode Delphi.

Comment: I recently obtained a free license from Embarcadero for 2007 because I am a registered user of XE2.  The offer was (IIRC) ANY legacy version of Delphi.  Try it.